# VBA SharePoint macro

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I am trying to connect to the sharepoint and loop through the folder with 3 excel files. While looping, I want to copy certain cells from each workbook and paste it into the template in my local drive. For each file found in sharepoint, I would like to have 3 new files created locally. I am facing the following issue now: Path is not found. I checked and the path is correct and I do have permission to access it. I also tried DIR method but it also didn't work for me for the same reason.

This is the code I have now:

```
 Sub CopyFromSharePoint()

 Dim folder As Object
 Dim file As Object
 Dim wb As Workbook
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim wb1 As Workbook
 Dim ws1 As Worksheet
 Dim myPath As String
 Dim newFile As String
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Dim fso As FileSystemObject
 Set fso = New FileSystemObject

 myPath="https://breeuropecom.sharepoint.com/teams/UserAutomation/ Rollover project/Test 3 files"
 Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set folder = fso.GetFolder(myPath)
 For Each file In folder.Files
     If UCase(Right(file.Name, 5)) = ".XLSX" Then
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(file.Path)
        Set ws = wb.Sheets("art166")
        Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\sadyrovac2531\Downloads\test.xls")
        Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("F506a")
        ws1.Cells(13, 7) = ws.Cells(1, 1)
        ws1.Cells(14, 10) = ws.Cells(11, 2)
        ws1.Cells(1, 18) = Replace(ws.Cells(2, 1), "Tax number: ", "")
        newFile = "C:\Users\sadyrovac2531\Documents" & file.Name
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=newFile, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
     ActiveWorkbook.Close
 End If
Next file

End Sub
```

Please let me know if you had a similar issue and fixed it or know how to fix it.

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot use FSO for working with content on a HTTP path.  It's not designed for that.  Same goes for `Dir()`   I would investigate syncing the folder to a local directory and working with that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to access a SharePoint folder as a local file system folder. However, SharePoint folders cannot be accessed directly as local folders. Instead, you need to use the SharePoint API or a SharePoint library to access the contents of the folder.

It might be easier to syncronize the SharePoint folder to a local folder via OneDrive and use the local path.

Answer (score 0):

This Macro is at least 10 years old, so things may be very different now, but this is how we used to open and close Workbooks, and navigate around those Workbooks, from SharePoint.

```
Sub OpenAndCloseWBFromSharePointFolder()

'If nobody has the file checked out
If Workbooks.CanCheckOut("http://43231/Shared Documents/ExcelList.xlsb") = True Then
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Open the file on the SharePoint server
Workbooks.Open Filename:="http://43231/Shared Documents/ExcelList.xlsb", UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksNever

'Close the workbook
Workbooks("ExcelList.xlsb").Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Else
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Open the File to check if you already have it checked out
Workbooks.Open Filename:="http://43231/Shared Documents/ExcelList.xlsb", UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksNever

'See if doc can be checked in
If Application.Workbooks("ExcelList.xlsb").CanCheckIn Then

'Check In, Save and Close
Application.Workbooks("ExcelList.xlsb").CheckIn SaveChanges:=True, Comments:="Checked-In before Delete"

'Open the file again
Workbooks.Open Filename:="http://43231/Shared Documents/ExcelList.xlsb"

'Close the workbook
Workbooks("ExcelList.xlsb").Close
End If
End If

End Sub
```